# Combinate two DataAnnotation validators (attributes)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, data-annotations

I'm trying to combine `RequiredIfNot` and `Range` validators, without success.
The deal is: when the condition on `RequiredIfNot` attribute is false, the `Range` attribute starts to work, but it doesn't work.

Actually, the code I have is...

```
[Range(1, 100, "Out of the range")]
[RequiredIfNot("Field", "Value", "This field is required")]
public string TVCount { get; set; }
```

... but the `Range` validator works everytime, and I want that it works only if `RequiredIfNot` condition were false.

Is there a way (simple or not) to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100300/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-by-data-annonation), you should just create you own Validation Attribute.

Comment: I think it's the best way, @Agat. Thanks!