# Custom Model validation in MVC4

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I am using Asp.net MVC4. I am having some entities and some rules for each entity which i need to validate from controller and display the 
curresponding error messages. I am trying to design a common validation class which can be used for all the entities that i am using. If I call 
the validation it should return me validation success or list of validation errors. I will be passing the entity and its type

Some sample entities and rules

```
    Employee - Employee should have either middle name or last name
             - First name, Middle name, last name should not be same
             - Should have address id and it should present in address table
             ......
             ......

     Address - In address line if there is an opening bracket it should have a matching closing bracket
             - If user give map url and it doesnt contains "http://" should show error message
            .......
            .......
```

I am having all the error message in a resource file with the error type id

Please advice me on which approch i should follow? or Share me some web tutorial link which will help me to design this

Comment: I will suggest you  or have a view here:


  http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/
  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16100455/3383479

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Remote Validation? this could be a good case for what you are trying to achieve as you have some complicated rules.

Some example code:

```
public class ValidationController : Controller 
{

  public JsonResult IsAddressValid(string Address) 
  {

     //if Address is valid
     return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    //else

   return Json("Address Not valid", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

  }
}
```

Then on your model

```
public class SignupModel
{
    [Required]
    [Remote("IsAddressValid", "Validation")]
    public string Address{ get; set; }
}
```