# MaxLength(data annotation) - Not working when used after trimming the string entered in the text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-annotations

I have a textbox which accepts 4 alphanumeric characters and spaces. 
For ex: `34 56` should be valid
`6789` is also valid.

```
$('#empIdtextbox1').on('blur', function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(val.replace(" ", ''));
});
```

and

```
[MaxLength(4, ErrorMessage = "The emp code cannot be more than 4 alphanumeric characters")]
```

`public string EmpId{ get; set; }`

However when I type `34 56`, It replaces the spaces but displays `The emp code cannot be more than 4 alphanumeric characters.`

Any input on this will be helpful

Comment: Try making that `keyup` rather than `blur`. That should strip the spaces out as you type.

Comment: I don't know much about dataannotations but I can assume that the validation's probably done before you are able to change the value.

Comment: instead of using 'blur' would it work with 'focusout' event instead. I think 'focusout' happens before; so it might work. Source http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-focusout

Comment: @zack.lore key up will make sure that space is not in that data. But I want it to allow adding space after the second character

Comment: Thanks @jyrkim focusout seems to work just like blur.  But it still displays the error till i come out of that textbox- Which is not right. Is there a way to trim it only when the space is after the second character.

Comment: @NoyGabay I think so. Is there a way to do validation after trimming data?

Comment: You could try a custom validation attribute [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100300/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-by-dataannotation).  You could just check for the position of the space and the length of the input in a way that suits your needs.

Comment: @testaccacc I guess the keyup would be then the most practical like zack.lore and Noy Gabay recommend. However, I think the data annotations could work if you allowed strings of length 5, and after blur did the trimming to 4 characters