# DataAnnotations Message with the invalid value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, modelstate

I'm building an ASP.NET Web API 2.
I'm serializing the JSON data to my model, which uses DataAnnotations, more specifically the Range and RegularExpression.

Everything works great, however, when the ModelState is not valid, I would like to be able to return all the invalid values back to the client.

Example:

```
public class Book {
    ...(fields removed for brevity)
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public int? Pages { get; set; }
}
```

Currently when the client sends a message with an invalid range(-1 for example), the returned message is: "The field Pages must be between 0 and 100."

I would like to return something like this: "The field Pages must be between 0 and 100. Current Value is -1."

Comment: You cant access the property value in an attribute (you can only use constants/static values). Not sure why you would need to do this (it should be obvious what the user has just entered) but you would need to override the `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add()` method and add your own message

Comment: You can always implement your own attribute to check model validations. Derive from `ValidationAttribute`.

Comment: Check out `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100300/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-by-dataannotation`

Comment: That works as I want. Thank you.

Comment: @user3455179, Note that will not give you client side validation

Answer (score 0):

Your Model could look like this:

```
 [Range(0,100)]
 [MinValue(0, "The field Pages must be between 0 and 100")]
 public int? Pages { get; set; }
```