# How to validate textbox with checkbox in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have This `ViewModel`:

```
   public string Address { get; set; }
   [DisplayName("Do you want Reward?")]
   public bool IsReward { get; set; }

   [Range(0,int.MaxValue,ErrorMessage="Please enter integer number")]

   [DisplayName("Reward")]
   public int Reward { get; set; }
```

In View `IsReward` property is unchecked by default, when user check `Isreward` and post the view, If `Reward` text box is empty then show an error message to the user "Please enter Reward".

How can I validate it using `DataAnnotation`?

Comment: You could write your own ValidationRule. Not really related specifically, but is an example of an implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16100455/858757 Another option to make it really simple is to check it in your controller and call AddModelError("Reward", "please enter Reward");

Comment: You can look at using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` or similar validation attribute applied to the `Reward` property - `[RequiredIfTrue("IsReward", ErrorMessage="please enter Reward")] public int Reward { get; set; }` which will give client and server side validation. If you want to write your own, [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) is a good guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. It will display the error message if `IsReward` is true and `Reward` textbox value is zero.

```
    [RewardValidation]
    public class RewardModel
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Do you want Reward ؟")]
        public bool IsReward { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter integer number")]

        [DisplayName("Reward")]
        public int Reward { get; set; }
    }

public class RewardValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        RewardModel app = value as RewardModel;
        if (app.IsReward && app.Reward==0)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "please enter Reward";

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And include the the `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` in view to display the message

Comment: it shows `The Reward field is required.` instead of ` please enter Reward` . whats a problem ?

Comment: @osmanRahimi, as per the if (app.IsReward && app.Reward==0) condition if the reward is 0 (zero) then only it will show the message 'please enter Reward'. 'The Reward field is required'  message triggers because the Reward data type is int. If suppose it is int? then it will never show the ' 'The Reward field is required'' message