# Validate Int on ViewModel to be ensure it is a number among a list of numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view model like this:

```
public class IndexVM
{
  [Required]
  // Must be either a 0, 5, 10, 25 or 50
  public int RadiusInMile { get; set; }
}
```

How can I tell MVC that the `int` **must** be either a `0`, `5`, `10`, `25` or a `50`? For anything other than those values `ModelState.IsValid` ought to return `false`.

I know about the `Range[]` validation attribute, but doesn't really work for me because I don't have a smooth range.

Comment: I'm just curious, what would you want to happen if you try to set it to something else. Shall it crash, throw an exception or just round it?

Comment: try [custom validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100300/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-by-dataannotation)

Comment: @D.Petrov I'd just return the user to the form like normally happens with an error message along the lines of `Your requested radius is not acceptable`. The user on the form select the radius from a pre-populated drop down of accepted values, but this is for validation purposes.

Comment: You could use a `[RegularExpression]` attribute. But a custom validation attribute would be more flexible

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought about Regular Expressions! Going to try this `[RegularExpression("^(0|5|10|25|50)$", ErrorMessage = "Please stick to values in the drop down for radius")]`