# Model validation with custom validation attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, data-annotations, modelstate, model-validation

I am using [model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) for my web API and I have following custom model as an example

```
public class Address
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The firstName is mandatory")]
    [EnhancedStringLength(100, ErrorCode = "1234556", ErrorMessage = "firstName must not exceed 100 characters")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public sealed class EnhancedStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    public EnhancedStringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength) : base(maximumLength)
    {
    }

    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
}
```

In my model validation filter I have following as an example

```
public class ModelValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return;
        }

        var errorViewModels = actionContext.ModelState.SelectMany(modelState => modelState.Value.Errors, (modelState, error) => new 
        {
            /*This doesn't work, the error object doesn't have ErrorCode property
            *ErrorCode = error.ErrorCode,
            **************************/
            Message = error.ErrorMessage,
        });


        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorViewModels);

        await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

What i would like to achieve is when input model fails validation (e.g. FirstName string length is more than 100 in this case) , I would like to output error code as well as error message, like this:

```
[{"errorCode":"1234556","message":"firstName must not exceed 100 characters"}]
```

But the problem is the ErrorCode isn't available when access the ModelState in the filter, the error object in this case is type `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelError` and doesn't contain errorcode property, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are extending ActionFilterAttribute but you actually want to extend ValidationAttribute.

For reference: [ASP.NET MVC: Custom Validation by DataAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100300/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-by-dataannotation)

Comment: Hey, that is not what I mean. I want to add my custom property (ErrorCode) to validation attribute , and I want it to be available in the ModelState, clear?

Comment: And I'm telling you that it's not the right way to approach that problem. You will not be able to add that property to the ModelState without ugly workarounds.