# Multiple Range Data Annotations on int in MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I need two ranges on an int in an MVC app

```
[Range(100, 200, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
[Range(500, 600, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Num Required")]
public int? Num { get; set; }
```

But only one Range DataAnnotation is allowed. How can I do this (ideally by using Data Annotations).

Can't find anything on Google.

thx.

Comment: You would need to create you own validation attribute - refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100300/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-by-dataannotation

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to achieve this

for example for range
[Range(10-23)]
[Range(99-99)]

you can use regular expression:
[RegularExpression("^(1[0-9]|2[0-3]|99)$")]

Use following regular expression for your case:[RegularExpression("^(10[0-9]|1[1-9]\d|[5-6]\d\d)$")]

Comment: Use following regular expression for your case:[RegularExpression("^(10[0-9]|1[1-9]\d|[5-6]\d\d)$")]

Answer (score 1):

Beside custom annotations you can use `IValidatableObject`:

```
public class YourViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
   public int? Num { get; set; }
   .
   .
   .
   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
      if (Num == null)
          return true;

      if((Num.Value >= 100 && Num.Value <= 200) || (Num.Value >= 500 && Num.Value <= 600))
              return true;

      return false
   }
}
```