# Limit Keys in a dictionary and number of characters of its value using Data Annotations

Tags: c#, data-annotations

Below is my request body for POST call to my web API.

```
  {
    "region" : "us-east-2",
    "namespaceName" : "com.xyx.demo.test",
    "tags": {
        "description": "Test Namespace",
        "purpose": "To store demo objects",
        ....
    }
  }
```

Here is the class that I am using to bind this request.

```
    public class Input
    {
        public string Region { get; set; }

        public string NamespaceName { get; set; }

        [Description("A set of key value pairs that define custom tags.")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to restrict my Tags Dictionary to create only 10 keys and each key's value should have not more than 256 characters.

So my `ModelState` should be invalid if more than 10 keys are provided or value contains more than 256 characters.

How can I do this using Data annotations ?

Comment: You can write custom validation annotation as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100300/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-by-dataannotation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a custom validation attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class YourAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!(value is Dictionary<string, string>))
            return new ValidationResult("Object is not of proper type");

        var dictionary = (Dictionary<string, string>)value;

        if (dictionary.Count > 10)
            return new ValidationResult("Dictionary cant have more than 10 items");

        foreach (var keyValuePair in dictionary)
        {
            if (keyValuePair.Value.Length > 256)
                return new ValidationResult("Value cant be longer than 256.");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Then your model

```
 public class Input
{
    public string Region { get; set; }

    public string NamespaceName { get; set; }

    [Description("A set of key value pairs that define custom tags.")]
    [YourAttribute]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any existing utility available fro that. Only choice is to write your own converter like below

https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/custom-converters-in-json-net-case-study-1/